# How to check VPN connection status on Android ICS

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, vpn

I'm trying to register receiver, that will check VPN status. I have tried this: [Get VPN Connection status on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3461967/get-vpn-connection-status-on-android) but looks like it no longer works on ICS. I have checked android source code for some clue, but with no luck, only noticed that in ISC there is nothing like: `vpn.connectivity` and `connection_state` - it use to be in android 2.3. Also tried using `android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE` as my `IntentFilter`, but it doesn't react on VPN connection at all (of course I have added permission `android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE`).
I thought that it is simple thing to do, but I already run out of ideas how to do it... Could someone help me with this please?

Answer (score 2):

May be you can try to poll for DNS server changes. If it has changed then VPN has connected. However, I think there could be a lot of exception to this rule.

[How do you get the current DNS servers for Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3070144/how-do-you-get-the-current-dns-servers-for-android)

Answer (score 0):

My solution is polling a NIC list.
 # You can get the list by executing command "ls /sys/class/net".

If the list has "tun0", the device already has connected to VPN.

Answer (score 0):

`NetworkCapabilities` worked for me in API 21+.  Unfortunately I haven't found a solution for 19-20. You have to loop over all existing networks and check which has `VPN_TRANSPORT`

```
ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager)mContext.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
Network[] networks = cm.getAllNetworks();

Log.i(TAG, "Network count: " + networks.length);
for(int i = 0; i < networks.length; i++) {

  NetworkCapabilities caps = cm.getNetworkCapabilities(networks[i]);

  Log.i(TAG, "Network " + i + ": " + networks[i].toString());
  Log.i(TAG, "VPN transport is: " + caps.hasTransport(NetworkCapabilities.TRANSPORT_VPN));
  Log.i(TAG, "NOT_VPN capability is: " + caps.hasCapability(NetworkCapabilities.NET_CAPABILITY_NOT_VPN));

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for (Enumeration<NetworkInterface> en =
             NetworkInterface.getNetworkInterfaces(); en.hasMoreElements(); ) {
            NetworkInterface intf = en.nextElement();
            if (intf.getName().contains("tun0") || intf.getName().contains("ppp0")) {
                vpnInterface = intf;
                break;
            }
        }
```

For the VPNNetwork Interface

```
for (Enumeration<InetAddress> en =
                 vpnInterface.getInetAddresses(); en.hasMoreElements(); ) {
                InetAddress address = en.nextElement();
                if (!address.isLoopbackAddress()) {
                    String ip = address.getHostAddress();
                    break;
                }
            }
```

and the InetAddress

Thats everything I know by the moment now

To check if it's up etc. maybe

```
if (vpnInterface.isUp())
```

I do have implemented a code which calls itself after a serveral time and send a message to the ApplicationHandlers