# How to add additional handlings to Vpn disconnection in Android?

Tags: android, vpn

I have a custom implementation of VpnService, which needs to perform some additional cleanup on disconnection. Everything works fine when I am stoping VpnService from my application using service bindings, but I need to perform that cleanup when client is disconnecting from the Vpn using system dialog.

So, how can I catch the disconnection and add some handlings to that?

[Get VPN Connection status on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3461967/get-vpn-connection-status-on-android) - this could be the solution, but it's not working on android 4+.

From logs point of view there are only two entries:

`03-20 03:27:09.478: INFO/Vpn(504): Switched from org.my.package to [Legacy VPN]`
`03-20 03:27:09.478: DEBUG/Vpn(504): setting state=IDLE, reason=prepare`

Comment: Is `onRevoke()` not called? http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/VpnService.html#onRevoke()

Comment: No, it is not. It looks like it's only called after I call `stopService()`.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I just ran into the same issue. VpnService.onRevoke() is not called.

It turns out this happens because I use a custom IBinder defined via AIDL wich I return from onBind(). VpnService implements onBind() too and returns an instance of VpnService.Callback.
Which is implemented this way:

```
private class Callback extends Binder {
    @Override
    protected boolean onTransact(int code, Parcel data, Parcel reply, int flags) {
        if (code == IBinder.LAST_CALL_TRANSACTION) {
            onRevoke();
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

VpnService.Callback does not use AIDL and just checks if the function code IBinder.LAST_CALL_TRANSACTION was sent. If so it executes onRevoke().

I integrated this code fragment in my custom IBinder implementation and now I receive the onRevoke() message. See the following example:

```
private final IBinder mBinder = new ServiceBinder();    
@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return mBinder;
}
public final class ServiceBinder extends ICustomVpnService.Stub
{
    ... implement methods defined in ICustomVpnService.Stub ....

    /**
     * Intercept remote method calls and check for "onRevoke" code which
     * is represented by IBinder.LAST_CALL_TRANSACTION. If onRevoke message
     * was received, call onRevoke() otherwise delegate to super implementation.
     */
    @Override
    public boolean onTransact(int code, Parcel data, Parcel reply, int flags)
    throws RemoteException
    {
        // see Implementation of android.net.VpnService.Callback.onTransact()
        if ( code == IBinder.LAST_CALL_TRANSACTION )
        {
            onRevoke();
            return true;
        }
        return super.onTransact( code, data, reply, flags );
    }

    private void onRevoke()
    {
        // shutdown VpnService, e.g. call VpnService.stopSelf()
    }
}
```

How did I figure it out? I searched the android source code for where onRevoke() is actually invoked. For that I find [grepcode (android)](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.2.2_r1/android/net/VpnService.java/#VpnService.onRevoke%28%29) pretty helpful. I often read the android source to understand how things work.

Comment: Great job! It's quite unfortunate, however, that Callback is a private class. Would be better off if one could create an instance of Callback and delegate the onTransact call to this instance. As of now we rely on code duplication...

Comment: Thanks, its save my day

Comment: No need to duplicate `VpnService`'s logic, see [other-answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39591917/8740349), which works as long as you don't **wrongly** (manually) set `VpnService.SERVICE_INTERFACE` as action.

Answer (score 6):

This happens if we use a custom `IBinder` defined via AIDL, which I return from onBind().

`VpnService` implements `onBind()` too and returns an instance of `VpnService.Callback` private-class.

### Solution:

```
@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    String action = intent != null ? intent.getAction() : null;
    if (action != null && action.equals(VpnService.SERVICE_INTERFACE)) {
        return super.onBind(intent);
    }

    return yourBinder;
}
```

> **Note** that above works as long as you never set `VpnService.SERVICE_INTERFACE` as action manually.
>
> That action should only be set by Android's internal-logic (automatically, never by our code manually).