# How to check if a network interface is a VPN in Android

Tags: android, android-networking, network-interface

I'm using the `ConnectivityManager` to check the network interfaces type in this manner:

```
NetworkInfo info = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
if(info.getType() == ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI)
    return "WIFI";
```

My problem is that I have to use API 19, while the `TYPE_VPN` value was introduced only in API 21.

How can I check if the interface is a VPN?

Comment: You will get that TYPE_VPN if you use the android system to connect to it, otherwise you will not right?

Comment: What? That value is part of the ConnectivityManager only in later APIs than what I have to use.

Comment: I mean Android doesnt know if you are connected to a VPN if its managed by an external app.

Comment: It can know what interfaces are up, give me a list of these interfaces, and then I can enumarate and query them using the code I wrote above. VPN can be one of the interfaces and I need a way to identify that the interface is of type VPN.

Comment: So you dont have the constant but what is returning the connectivity manager? in that case? can you check it?

Comment: The connectivity manager is the same one as the regular in android: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/ConnectivityManager.html#TYPE_VPN

Comment: Then if getType == 17 its VPN

Comment: ok.. is it possible that the getType won't return 17 since maybe that value was also introduced in API 21? (I'm not sure if it was, but just to be sure)

Comment: That is what i was asking, connect to vpn and test it to see what value is returning.

Comment: Check this out : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28386553/check-if-a-vpn-connection-is-active-in-android