# Detect if an always-on VPN is configured on Android

Tags: android, network-programming, vpn

I have an Android VPN application. When I fire the intent to start the VPN (via [VPNService.prepare](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/VpnService#prepare(android.content.Context))), it fails immediately if there's an always-on VPN already configured on the device. That seems reasonable, but I'd like to be able to easily detect that case, so I can show a helpful message to the user.

By 'always on' I mean the specific VPN always-on Android VPN flag: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/vpn#always-on

I can't seem to find a way to access that info, even though it is used internally in Android (e.g. [here](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/packages/VpnDialogs/src/com/android/vpndialogs/ConfirmDialog.java#77) but that `getAlwaysOnVpnPackage` doesn't seem to be available publicly AFAICT).

The best option I've seen is [Check if a VPN connection is active in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28386553/check-if-a-vpn-connection-is-active-in-android), which will tell you if any VPN connection is currently active, but that's not enough, because:

- I don't want to know about temporary VPN connections: I'm only interested if it's an *always-on* VPN connection.
- Sometimes 'always-on' connections aren't actually always on. If you have a disconnected connection and set it as 'always-on', it's configured as such, and blocks all other VPN installs, but there's no network connection created (Android shows a persistent warning instead, which takes you to the other app to activate the connection). Because there's no connection, the above technique doesn't work. I still need to detect this case, since it still blocks my VPN setup.

**Is there any way to check whether the device currently has a VPN configured as 'always-on'?**

Comment: This was closed for covering more than one problem, which I think is a misunderstanding of the question. There's a couple of examples here, but they're examples of the same single problem: I want to access info about the current VPN configurations, not the active VPN network connections. I've added more detail to try & clarify that.

Comment: AFAIK, you need to be a device owner/manager to get this info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the end, it seems this isn't possible on a normal device any way that I can find. I think is possible if you're a device admin, but that requires managed enterprise devices etc.

For now, I've handled this by watching for near-instant (less than 200ms) VPN setup failures (between running `startActivityForResult(vpnIntent)` and receiving `onActivityResult` with `RESULT_CANCELED`) and then showing a helpful message in that case.

Full implementation is in https://github.com/httptoolkit/httptoolkit-android/commit/928fbf92a4f868042789471be0d42800a226194b in case you're trying to do the same.

Answer (score 5):

You can use this method

```
private fun isVpnAlwaysOn(): Boolean {
    return if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP_MR1) {
        val alwaysOn = Settings.Secure.getString(contentResolver, "always_on_vpn_app")
        return !alwaysOn.isNullOrEmpty()
    } else false
}
```

'alwaysOn' contains the package name of the app for which always-on is configured.

Comment: This will no longer work with Android 12 and above. If you use this, you will get `java.lang.SecurityException: Settings key: <always_on_vpn_app> is not readable. From S+, settings keys annotated with @hide are restricted to system_server and system apps only, unless they are annotated with @Readable.`

Comment: anyone can find a work around for Android 12+ from >  https://github.com/celzero/rethink-app/commit/b028a6085111d515d872952d28ab336ea7bc6923