# how to detect if a user is using VPN to access my Android app?

Tags: android, android-studio, mobile

I am making an app for only a specific country, let's say for American people. and I only want American people to use my app. but many people will try to use my app on American servers using VPN.
how can I detect and prevent those users.
User need to create an account and login to my app to use it and i am using firebase for database.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28386553/check-if-a-vpn-connection-is-active-in-android Has a couple options for you to try out.