# Detect VPN running in Android Phone

Tags: java, android, android-connectivitymanager

I am trying to detect if VPN is running on the phone. I have implemented the below code, but it reports crashes on Firebase Crashlytics.

```java
ConnectivityManager connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager) activity.getSystemService(activity.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
    @SuppressLint("MissingPermission")
    Network activeNetwork = connectivityManager.getActiveNetwork();
    @SuppressLint("MissingPermission")
    NetworkCapabilities caps = connectivityManager.getNetworkCapabilities(activeNetwork);
    boolean vpnInUse = caps.hasTransport(NetworkCapabilities.TRANSPORT_VPN);
```

The crash reported is

> Fatal Exception: java.lang.RuntimeException Unable to resume activity
> {com.my.app/com.my.app.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException:
> Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean
> android.net.NetworkCapabilities.hasTransport(int)' on a null object
> reference

How do I resolve this issue?

Comment: `caps` is `null`, what else we can insight... just make some preventing `if(caps!=null)`...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Check if a VPN connection is active in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28386553/208273)

Answer (score 1):

`caps` is `null`, what else we can insight... just make some preventing `if(caps!=null)`... below some shorten way for checking `null` state

```
NetworkCapabilities caps = connectivityManager.getNetworkCapabilities(activeNetwork);
boolean vpnInUse = caps!=null && caps.hasTransport(NetworkCapabilities.TRANSPORT_VPN);
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are getting null reference of NetworkCapabilities.
Please look into the [developer.android docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/ConnectivityManager#getNetworkCapabilities(android.net.Network)).

This document says

> This will return null if the network is unknown or if the |network|
> argument is null. This will remove any location sensitive data in
> TransportInfo embedded in NetworkCapabilities#getTransportInfo(). Some
> transport info instances like WifiInfo contain location sensitive
> information. Retrieving this location sensitive information (subject
> to app's location permissions) will be noted by system. To include any
> location sensitive data in TransportInfo, use a **NetworkCallback**
> with NetworkCallback#FLAG_INCLUDE_LOCATION_INFO flag.